# Receive file in C over network

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to receive a file over my home network without much success. I am able to receive only approx. 10 chars with this code provided and am unable to make much progress. My send function on the server side works fine and am 99% sure there is something going on in this code that I'm not understanding. If someone can kindly explain what I did wrong and what I should do that would be much appreciated! I am aware of the proper error code and checking that should be added but just to keep everything tidy I have included the heavy lifting code.

```
//********************** CLIENT CODE BELOW(RECEIVE FILE)**
#include "StartConnection.h"

#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FILENAME "/Users/name/Desktop/holaS.txt"
#define LENGTH (512)

// port number where to port in application
#define PORT_NUMBER (2005)

int clientSocket;
char buffer[LENGTH];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
socklen_t addr_size;

void setup(){
    clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //socket create
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // settings

    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER); // port connection#
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//ip localhost

    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    // bind
    addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
    connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

    /* FOR SENDING TEXT TO CONSOLE/REVEIVE
    recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
    Print the received message
    printf("Data received: %s",buffer);
    */

    rec_file(); // our entry
    close(clientSocket);
}

char rec_file() {
    recv(clientSocket, buffer, 512, 0);

    int file_size = 0;
    ssize_t len;

    int remain_data = 0;
    file_size = atoi(buffer); //512

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(FILENAME,"ab+");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("File Failed To Write");
    }

    remain_data = file_size;

    //
    while(((len = recv(clientSocket,buffer, buffer, 0)) >0) && (remain_data > 0)){
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len,file);
    }

    return 0;
}




//*********** SERVER CODE (SEND FILEBELOW*******************************************
#define PORT_NUMBER (2005)
int welcomeSocket, newSocket;
char buffer[512];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
socklen_t addr_size;

void start_server(){
    welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // create socket

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //type
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);

    // localhost ip
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

    // bind address
    bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    // wait for connection max 5 connections
    if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
        printf("Listening\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");

    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage; // accept <=5

    newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *&serverStorage, &addr_size);

    printf("\n OK PRINT MESSAGE");

    // char info[100];
    // scanf("%s",&info);
    // strcpy(buffer,info); // for writing text to client
    // send(newSocket,buffer,13,0);

    send_file(); // or entry function for our file send

    close(welcomeSocket);
}

void send_file(){
    /*
        char file_name[100];

        printf("Please Print Name of your File You Wish To Send");
        scanf("%s",&file_name);
    */

    FILE *f = fopen("/Users/name/Desktop/numbers.txt", "rb");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    long fsize = ftell(f);

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);  //same as rewind(f);

    char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);

    fread(string, fsize, 1, f);

    printf("\n Sending File");

    send(newSocket,string,13,0);

    fclose(f);

    printf("%s",string);

    string[fsize] = 0;
    free(string);
}
```

Comment: the code is missing the declarations and initialization of `buffer` and `clientSocket`. Plus in the `while` you use buffer twice once as a buffer once to give the length. If buffer is an array I think you want `sizeof buffer` there.

Comment: in addition to @KamiKaze; are you sure the server is working "just fine"? what is the first thing you send from the server? is it a string "10"?

Comment: You need to show how you declare `buffer`. The way you use it seems very odd and is - most likely - wrong. Especially the second `recv`call is odd. There you pass `buffer` as length parameter (which is size_t). Maybe you wanted to pass 512? BTW: Have you tried to do a simple print of `file_size`? Also you don't check the return value of the first `recv`.

Comment: As it stands *if* (hint!)  this `remain_data > 0` was true once it would stay true forever.

Comment: Code doing complete error checking is code providing debugging for free.

Comment: I have updated with the complete code. As I had it when I asked the question. I will take the points mentioned into consideration and test. In the mean time I will research, thanks. @alk i'm going to take a closer look at that and try and get it working.  ** I should have mentioned this is inside of a C++ application and is called upon using extern "C"{ "my filename.h"}

Comment: did you get file size correct? Did you look with a debugger? THings will not go well if that step fails

Comment: @pm100 I'm troubleshooting right now and getting out a few books to investigate. I will be back on in the evening to update, thanks

Comment: i mean - set a breakpoint in rec_file and inspect file_size right after the atoi. Or even add a printf for it

Answer (score 1):

As other people have already pointed out, there are a few obvious issues with this code, like:

```
while(((len = recv(clientSocket,buffer, buffer, 0)) >0) && (remain_data > 0)){
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len,file);
}
```

Should be:

```
while(((len = recv(clientSocket,buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) >0) && (remain_data > 0)){
    remain_data -= len;
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len,file);
}
```

However, the whole client/server code is awkward. You may want to check something like "Beej's Guide to Network Programming", and start from one of the examples given there.

Comment: I have modified that loop you are referring to. I am still unable to receive my file but upon further investigation; comparing my file size  and actual bytes sent to the client it's not adding up so I am currently fixing the server side... thanks for that recommendation for "Beej's" its proving to be quite helpful in the underlining logic.

Answer (score 0):

This was difficult to get correct. There was a lot of reading man pages and referring to different code to try and get something working, admittedly this is my first time working with C sockets and I'm glad i struggled because I learned about sockets and other things in the process. So what happened was both sides were incorrect. Using simple text like "hey how are you" and sending a 1 GB file is different but the same in a sense. A proper loop with the correct logic needs to be used as well as a file descriptor the loops needs to have buffered data and read into the send socket and as you can imagine on the receiving end needs to be read in a buffer as well. What really won this battle for me was this PDF (sorry I lost the link but have the name, type in google and you will more than likely find it) ** "Dr. Mostafa Hassan Dahshan College of Computer and Information Sciences
King Saud University " ***  This gives a detailed example(s) how to use the sockets properly and you can dissect and see whats going on. I don't want to post my code out of tough love for the community but this book will help you arrive at the same conclusion.

Comment: Heres the link: faculty.ksu.edu.sa/mdahshan/CEN463FA09/07-file_transfer_ex.pdf       He seems to have a lot of other pdf's as well and worth looking into.